# Gradle: accessing project classes & dependencies from custom task

Tags: java, gradle

I am writing a custom Gradle task (in Java) using the buildSrc approach. I'd like the task to actually bootstrap the core module's Spring context, so the custom task class looks something like:

**`buildSrc/main/java/CustomTask.java:`**

```
import org.gradle.api.DefaultTask;
import org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskAction;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;

public class CustomTask extends DefaultTask {

    @TaskAction
    public void run() {
        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("core-context.xml");
    }
}
```

However, the task fails to compile due to Spring not being available. Spring is a compile dependency of the core module of course.

What's the best way to tell Gradle that the buildSrc source set depends on the module's source set? (Ideally in a way that won't require duplicating the dependency declarations).

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "I'd like the task to actually bootstrap the core module's Spring context"? What's the purpose of the task?

Comment: The purpose of the task is to get Hibernate's schema updates (not run them). Since everything is configured with Spring, I'd like to not repeat any configs, but use the project's natural configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to add the main build's compiled code to the buildscript class path, since that class path is constructed before any task (e.g. `compileJava`) has run. Instead, you could implement a solution based around a class loader that's populated with, say, `sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath`. Typically, `CustomTask` wouldn't itself know about this, but would get *configured* with the appropriate class path.

Comment: Wow. I've added Spring & Hibernate to the buildSrc/build.gradle for now, and managed to grab the main source set's runtimeClasspath in the plugin apply(). In other words I used a less than-ideal solution for the compile problem, and am now faced with the runtime problem. Is there really no other way to add the project's runtime cp to the build script/task cp other than a custom class loader?

Comment: Alternatively, you could run the code in a separate JVM. This probably isn't easier but it is safer, as there is no risk of polluting the Gradle (daemon) JVM (memory leaks etc.). A class loader populated with `sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath` will already contain Spring and Hibernate, provided they are declared as dependencies in the main build.

Comment: Thinking more about this, can't you just add a main class to the main build that does what you want, and run it using a `JavaExec` task? That seems a lot simpler.

Comment: Yes I think something simpler like that will have to be the solution. I just didn't want to pollute the project with build code. I thought buildSrc is a good way to achieve that. I guess the next best thing is a 'buildUtils' subproject with a main method and a dep on :core.